# How to make uniform indenting inside expressions too?

Tags: intellij-idea, indentation

Sometimes I break complex expressions into lines too. I wish them to be of the same indenting as when indentin brackets, i.e. indenting X extra spaces for each extra nesting, like here:

```
 @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return
            super.hashCode() ^
            Objects.hashCode(numPatches) ^
            Objects.hashCode(W) ^
            Objects.hashCode(b)
            ;
    }
```

Unfortunately, IntelliJ all the time tries to overcome me.

How to win?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand what the current behavior is, but I think "Smart indent" is the setting you want to change.

[image: indent settings]

If that doesn't do the trick for you, take a look at the "Tabs and Indents" settings in Code Style.

[image]